# Methodology for boundary inspection

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, topology, alignment

I have two datasets:

1. parcel layers
2. an overlaid boundary layer

When the boundary was initially drawn it was never snapped to the parcel boundaries. We now need to conduct reviews around the entire perimeter to ensure it aligns with features/boundaries.

Is there a quick way to run a boundary investigation?

Even symbolizing the overlap or identifying where it should be snapped to the boundary.

Comment: How much area? I have a million acres to map, so nothing would be super quick for me.

Comment: Do you topology rules set up?

Comment: You have tags for ArcGIS Desktop and ArcMap but make no mention of using that software in your question body.  If you are using ArcMap, then what have you tried?